# RESTful interface for ECG/EEG sensor data in haskell

Tags: rest, haskell, restful-architecture

I'm working on a project in which I want to display biosensor EEG/ECG data measured by a portable device (e.g., a micro controller with wireless data transmission via Wifi or Bluetooth). For this purpose, I need to interface with the portable device/microcontroller, for which the many or some of the device seem to use [RESTful interfaces](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm), but offer also probably sockets.

One example of microcontroller with wifi is the ["spark.io"](http://docs.spark.io/hardware/), which is based on a cortex m3 and CC3000 wireless controller for WiFi access on-board. The data to be transferred are around 500 to 1000 float values per second, which should arrive at the REST client with as little delay as possible. Probably an non-REST approach like sockets would fit better, but I would still like to test an approach based on a RESTFul interface (a tiny argument for this would be that transferring data via RESFul interface seems very common and has good library support).

*Q: The question is, what is the best approach for a performant (in the sense of near-realtime) implementation that interfaces with this via REST interface?*

I am sure this problem has been solved before, but I could not quickly find a paper via google scholar or technical/scientific blog post that explains this. The only link I found is on ["rest hooks"](http://resthooks.org/docs/), but I am not sure if this is a good approach. Searching on SE didn't reveal a past question on this.

Side note: My approach would be to implement the interface in haskell first to test the design and performance of the RESFull interface. Later the working approach should be ported or implemented with Java/Android/spark.io/some other microcontroller.

(Please note this question is entirely about the architecture and not at all about haskell libraries or anything. If using REST is the stupiest thing, I will accept that as an answer if it is argumented. Also then the question is then whether in general microcontroller web-interfaces and specically their APIs, like that of ["spark.io"](http://docs.spark.io/hardware/), are in general a stupid idea, if they are implemented via REST. Is this the case? If not, what definition of "near real time" justifies that a REST interface is a bad idea and thus other means of communcation are better. Like: one sensor read per minute? Or, one per second, by 1/10 second, by 1/100 second, by 1/1000 second?)

Comment: I don't believe REST is a good paradigm for real-time monitoring.

Comment: I agree, as stated in the question. @protonfish: what do you think is the best option? An theoretically, can it be done? If yes, how can you do it in REST if it were a requirement to use it.

Comment: Every sensor value can hava an ID in milliseconds (or in microseconds), so the IDs are ordered. The REST api can provide the ID of the last measured sensor value. Further, the REST api can provide sensor results that occured between two IDs, e.g., GET fromID=.... & toID=... If you then poll that REST interface every 0.1 seconds, it should be possible to receive 500 or 1000 float values per second. This is a research project, I don't assume that there will be more than one client (or server) at any given time.

Comment: I hate to be unhelpful, but I'd do whatever way worked and tell the boss it was REST - he'll never know the difference. I have no expertise with lower-level communications or what libraries are at your disposal in Haskell. Sorry.

Comment: Extending on Protonfish's comment: get the data off the microcontroller to a less-restricted computer in the most efficient way possible, and provide a REST API from there for the rest of the world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, let's go through this.

REST is not necessarily a bad idea but it has a lot of features which you may not need. For example, there are REST verbs not just for retrieval, but also updating, deleting, and creating resources. If those functions are important (e.g. you need to send certain control data to the EEG controller) then REST will be nice. If you just want fast access to the stream of data, consider raw TCP instead.

Similarly, REST will package messages into "requests" and their "responses" which come with a bunch of "headers" indicating things like whether the request could be fulfilled, whether it's compressed, etc. These can be great features but may be bloat. You'll probably want to emit enough data on each request so that the ~1kB of headers are a small fraction of it. But given 8-byte floats (`double`s),  that requires transmitting 500-1000 data points, which you've said will take about one second. Is that our fate -- to always have 1s of latency?

REST will allow you to avoid some of that bloat by declaring a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` so that the client can operate on individual chunks as they become available. So that's an architectural decision that I think will need to be made.

I would definitely get `Keep-Alive` working as soon as possible, and it would be my chief feature when looking for what library to use on the server. `Keep-Alive` is a standard extension to HTTP which avoids tearing down and rebuilding the TCP stack for each HTTP request. If you don't do this then you have some heavy protocol negotiations each time you send a request.

A crucial decision you'll have to make involves whether you want to do [HTTP pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining) or not. You can combine HTTP pipelining with longer-lived requests (ones where you don't expect an immediate response) to essentially "send the data when it becomes available" (i.e. send the headers first and let the server push out the data when it's good and ready). This is an alternative to chunked transfers.

If you can work those out, then HTTP is regularly used to send megabytes per second, so your use case fits well within what REST is capable of. In terms of REST/HTTP libraries for Haskell, if you have to somehow program the controller yourself, the big options are `wai`, `yesod`, `snap`, and `rest`. If you just need an HTTP client there are a few of those too.

Comment: This is an exceptionally well written answer to my question and provides the missing information I was lacking.